# implicit conversion of 'unsigned long 'UIUserNotificationSettings *' is disallowed with arc

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode6, ios8

Push notification in iOS 8 Doesn't work.

Error display:

```
implicit conversion of 'unsigned long 'UIUserNotificationSettings *' is disallowed with arc
```

Code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)];
    return YES;
}
```

[image]
I'm using ios 8.0 and xcode 6 beta.

Comment: Yes http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/23/1401769751-capture-d-ecran-2014-06-03-a-06-07-26.png

Comment: Seems the API may NDA'd so haven't looked at the docs, but the compilation error looks like registerUserNotificationSettings expects a pointer to the settings instead of the settings themselves. In other words, you may want to take a closer look at the docs.

Comment: This is in violation of Apples NDA agreement. You can not post questions in a public forum about iOS 8 or Xcode 6. Those questions must be asked on the Apple developer forums until the products are officially released.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Is it? This year, Apple has lifter the NDA... even the documentation is publicly available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am getting from [below from official documentation of iOS 8.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html)

> - Apps that use local or push notifications must explicitly register the types of alerts that they display to users by using a UIUserNotificationSettings object. This registration process is separate from the process for registering remote notifications, and users must grant permission to deliver notifications through the requested options.
> - Local and push notifications can include custom actions as part of an alert. Custom actions appear as buttons in the alert. When tapped, your app is notified and asked to perform the corresponding action. Local notifications can also be triggered by interactions with Core Location regions.

And also read

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationSettings_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIUserNotificationSettings

AND

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings:

**So Answer should be..**

```
/// First register notification setting with settings type like 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; // you can also set here for local notification.
```

Comment: i dont understand 

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
    
    return YES;
}`

Comment: So you mentioned the NDA, and then promptly violated it? ;)

Comment: No, it's not unter NDA. §10.1 iOS Developer Program License Agreement: You will not be bound by the foregoing confidentiality terms with regard to technical information about pre-release Apple Software and services disclosed by Apple at WWDC (Apple’s Worldwide Developers Conference), except that You may not post screen shots, write public reviews or redistribute any pre-release Apple Software or services.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(NSUInteger)notificationTypes categories:(NSSet *)categories
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:notificationTypes categories:categories]];
    }
    else if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}
```

Try [UIUserNotificationSettings-Extension](https://github.com/alexruperez/UIUserNotificationSettings-Extension), provides helper methods that will make you much easier to handle the new #iOS8 #Interactive #Notifications.

Comment: Note that Apple recommends calling registerForRemoteNotifications only after registerUserNotificationSettings: has completed (namely the application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: has been called).

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the log provided during run-time.
At first, without user registration of local events, the log does suggest

`UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Wednesday, 4 June 2014 9:27:24 pm India Standard Time, user info = (null)} with an alert but haven't received permission from the user to display alerts`.

This is iOS 8.

And so, in this case, you also need to use

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil]];`

in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// are you running on iOS8?

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) 
  {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeSound) categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  } 
else // iOS 7 or earlier
  {
    UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to handle both iOS 8 and anything less than iOS 8

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```