# Getting sound notification for alarm set

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert

With the appdelegate.m code shared by you in below link, my error of xcode asking for user authorization for alerts is removed now 
[Ask for User Permission to Receive UILocalNotifications in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100313/ask-for-user-permission-to-receive-uilocalnotifications-in-ios-8/27112365#27112365)

But, I am not able to get any notification sound on given time set (though I get message pop up which i set "Time to Wake up")

What could be issue? Please help

Comment: You get a sound only if (1) you ask for a sound and (2) the user does not suppress the sound for your notifications. Prove, by showing your code, that you are asking for a sound.