# Local notification scheduled but not fired

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uilocalnotification, swift2

local notification not firing when firing when time ia set in UTC format

```
2017-08-23 20:23:27 +0000 // time to fire local notification

func schedule_Local_notification(alert_body: String, alertDate: NSDate) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
    print("local notication scheduled at \(alertDate)")
    notification.fireDate = alertDate
    notification.alertBody = alert_body
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

The above function prints the value 'local notication scheduled at 2017-08-23 20:23:27 +0000'

Can anyone help to resolve this issue

Comment: It's not 20:23 yet.

Comment: now time is 20:36 here

Comment: It might be, but it's not UTC then.

Comment: how to resolve this

Comment: Can you print out alertDate ? Where does it come from ?

Comment: Have you written function for userNotification? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100313/ask-for-user-permission-to-receive-uilocalnotifications-in-ios-8

Comment: '2017-08-23 20:23:27 +0000' is the date.. alert date is printed correctly but notification is not fired @DamienBannerot

Comment: yeah included permission and pop up appears on installing the app