# Apple 4.5.4 guidelines causing app rejection

Tags: ios, app-store, uilocalnotification

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 4.5.4 Push Notifications must not be required for the app to function, and should not be used for advertising, promotions, or direct
>   marketing purposes or to send sensitive personal or confidential
>   information.

I block UI by showing a message `notification required to set reminders`

After submitting 10 binaries my 11th binary is rejected because of  this reason.

I replied that my app is a reminder app and I am not using any remote notification, App required notifications permission to alert the user, without notifications user can miss important reminders.

But this reason is not accepted.

What would I do.

---

I am asking permission for this notification

[image]

Comment: Check if your app is registering for remote notifications and remove that code.

Comment: Nope no remote notification.

Comment: The problem is that your does not function with out notifications (local or push). Which is not allowed, apps have to function without the notification being turned on.

Comment: You can’t block the operation of your app if notifications aren’t enabled. It may be that the user won’t get any benefit from your app if they don’t enable notifications and you can explain this to them, but ultimately it is their choice. If they decide to install your app and not enable notifications then that is their problem,  not yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can not force user to allow notification for your app. Otherwise there is no meaning of this setting 'allow your app to send notification`.

So, you should not block `UI`, but you should manage your app such a way that not block any `UI`!

And guidelines you have posted is about `push notification` not for local and you tagged your question with local notification.

Comment: yeah this is remote or push notification! it is not local notification!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100313/ask-for-user-permission-to-receive-uilocalnotifications-in-ios-8